# How to login to PhpMyAdmin with a Deck.app mysql instance?

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, containers, multipass

Using the deck app, that uses Multipass & Docker to build containers and instances of specific technologies (such as Laravel, CodeIgnite, Apache, etc.,) to create a mysql instance it installs a copy of phpmyadmin and allows you to view the server through the browser.

[image: screenshot of the deck app with mysql instance]

I cannot logon to the phpmyadmin page that is created by this mysql/phpmyadmin instance in the deck app

[image: login screen for the phpmyadmin instance]

I have messed around using CLI (terminal) to initiate the server to make it active, however this generally resulted in errors.

I have web hosting that allows me to use remote myqsl through cpanel but I don't know how to connect it to a localhost.

I would like to know how to login or use the mysql server.

I would appreciate advice on what I need to do to make this new mysql instance usable, so I can get a username, password & database name to utilise in a laravel project.

I would also like to know if there is any better solution for creating a mysql & phpmyadmin database to use for a laravel project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have messed around using CLI (terminal) to initiate the server to make it active, however this generally resulted in errors.

What are the errors?

> I have web hosting that allows me to use remote myqsl through cpanel but I don't know how to connect it to a localhost.

You wouldn't; you'll want to install your own phpMyAdmin locally rather than connecting your web host to your local server. You should not expose your local database server to the internet.

> I would like to know how to login or use the mysql server.

Using the password you set during installation, or if you weren't prompted, usually it's a blank password.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up solving the issue. It related back to a rookie error when installing the app, it was in a file folder that had a space in it, which caused error for all of the web applications associated with it.